# How to force a postback with asp.net and C#

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a demo scheduled with a client and i need a quick and dirty fix for now. I will find a more appropriate work around tomorrow but for the time being i need a way to force a post back, or refresh the page.

i tried:

```
Response.Redirect("");
```

but it brings me to a page that says "Object moved to here". 'here' is a hyperlink that brings me to the page with desired results but i wish to bypass this message.

Any ideas.

Comment: Post some code for what you're trying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

(or whatever the name of the current page is)

Comment: Many thank yous Travis.
I'm still unsure why Response.Redirect("") didn't work.

Comment: you didn't redirect to anything. If you want to redirect put in path information. If you want to redirect to the configured default page you could put Response.Redirect(".") and Response.Redirect("/") would put you at the configured root default page.

Answer (score 5):

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawURL);
```

This also works and you won't need to worry about putting in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Response.Redirect() is not the greatest because there is not state. It's a new request. if you want to keep state of all your controls then use the __doPostBack method which is added automatically by ASP when the page is rendered so it's accessible from client side:

you can do this:

or just call it from javascript:

__doPostBack('myElementId','');

Alternatively you can just use javascript code:

document.forms[0].submit();

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just add a javascript block with `window.reload()` in it?

[Here](http://sohelruet.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/how-to-add-javascript-at-runtime-using-c-in-aspnet-20/) is some useful info on how to do this correctly in Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The server can not tell the client to reload.

You can use the html meta refresh:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://the.new.url">
```

but that will not do a proper post back i think.

Content is how many seconds the client waits to do the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASP.NET AJAX Timer Control!
http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a post back to populate a list? Did you look into if solving it with Ajax could help??

Or if you just need a quick and dirty thing, just fake it and fix it later.