# Forcing a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Is there a way to force a postback in code?

I'm looking to force the raising of a postback from a method in the c# code behind my asp.net web application.

Comment: Can you be more specific - and tell us what approaches you have tried so far?

Comment: eh, a postback is from client (browser) to server. So C# code (that runs on the server) can't do that.

Comment: I think your question is similar to the one raised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418532/how-to-force-a-postback-with-asp-net-and-c-sharp)

Comment: @Richard Ev I'm looking to dynamically add UserControls to the web app. Clicking a button will increment the number of controls, but the new control will not be displayed until the `Page_Load` method fires on postback (after the next button click). So I need to force a postback at the end of the method that increments the number of controls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force full post-back from a button within an UpdatePanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545508/how-do-i-force-full-post-back-from-a-button-within-an-updatepanel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A postback is triggered after a form submission, so it's related to a client action...
take a look here for an explanation:
[ASP.NET - Is it possible to trigger a postback from server code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650/asp-net-is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-postback-from-server-code)

and here for a solution:
http://forums.asp.net/t/928411.aspx/1

Comment: For those using newer versions of .NET, you have to use `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` since 'this.GetPostBackEventReference(...)' is obsolete. Also probably `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can try redirecting to same page.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Comment: But then the form values are lost…

Comment: @Protectorone not unless you ViewState[] them first and reload on the subsequent postback in Page_Load()

Answer (score 6):

Simpler:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "DoPostBack", "__doPostBack(sender, e)", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the solution from http://forums.asp.net/t/928411.aspx/1 as mentioned by mamoo - just in case the website goes offline. Worked well for me.

```
StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();

sbScript.Append("<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>\n");
sbScript.Append("<!--\n");
sbScript.Append(this.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "PBArg") + ";\n");
sbScript.Append("// -->\n");
sbScript.Append("</script>\n");

this.RegisterStartupScript("AutoPostBackScript", sbScript.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not from code behind. A postback is a request initiated from a page on the client back to itself on the server using the Http POST method. On the server side you can request a redirect but the will be Http GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data-bound control like the `Repeater` or `ListView`, re-bind it to a list of control properties as needed, and let it generate the controls dynamically.

As an alternative, you can use `Response.Redirect(".")` to re-load the same page.

Answer (score 1):

By using Server.Transfer("YourCurrentPage.aspx"); we can easily acheive this and it is better than Response.Redirect(); coz Server.Transfer() will save you the round trip.

Comment: Doesn't this reset the form fields? I guess it's like a fresh page call which means user-inputs like filters would be undone (if they aren't stored in session).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually call the method invoked by PostBack from the `Page_Load` event:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyPostBackMethod(sender, e);
}
```

But if you mean if you can have the `Page.IsPostBack` property set to `true` without real post back, then the answer is no.