# How to get my gridview updated without any postback once AjaxFileUpload completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxFileUpload in ASP.NET 4.0 website and I have one gridview to show the uploaded file list upon update.

I'm using AjaxFileUpload FileUploadComplete function to save uploaded file list & bind into my gridview. However, **my problem is the gridview with databind doesn't showed up on the page instantly & it'll show only after postback**.

Any one can advise how to trigger postback once file upload complete OR how to make my gridview updated without any postback?

Appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: To trigger a postback from the server, refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209944/forcing-a-postback).

Comment: get the HTML of gridview after binding it as a response of your fileupload call

Comment: Postback from server code as suggested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209944/forcing-a-postback won't work in case of AjaxFileUpload as this control submitting to hidden frame or uploading file with File API in case of modern browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tested forced postback but it doesn't help. Still the same.

Comment: @Amy since there are to few chances that question will be reopened I posted solution here: http://pastebin.com/jTawLzGJ

Comment: Thanks, Yuriy. Now, i solved it as workaround way to use ajax collapse panel to trigger postback upon expand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try placing the grid in an ajax updatepanel and adding the FileUpload control's FileUploadComplete event as a trigger to the panel. That way when the event is executed the grid's updatepanel will do its own postback and update the grid.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I tested but there is no option for me to tag the FileUploadComplete event. I can only tag FileUpload control as trigger. Any advice. Thanks.